# Complement of Donaldson's symplectic submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, holomorphic-symplectic

I am just starting to learn more symplectic geometry on Stein manifolds.  I understand that an important class of Stein manifolds arises as the complement of a Donaldson's codimension two symplectic submanifold.  I was wondering where I can find an actual proof of this important fact.  Any comments or explanations will be more than welcome.

Answer (score 3):

S. K. Donaldson, [Symplectic submanifolds and almost-complex geometry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1438190), J. Differential Geom. **44**, 666 (1996).

For more info, and the link to Bertini's theorem, see Jonathan Evans' thesis: [Symplectic topology of some Stein and rational surfaces](http://www.homepages.ucl.ac.uk/~ucahjde/thesis.pdf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the posting. Can you fill in with more details? In the complex projective case, the complement of a hypersurface $V$ is stein because there is a pluri-harmonic function $\log \vert\vert s\vert\vert^2$, where $s$ is a holomorphic section which vanishes exactly at $V$. In the almost complex case, how can we proceed?

Comment: I checked out Donaldson's paper and found out that Donaldson actually proved that the complement of his submanifold is Stein. An argument can be found in the proof of Lefschetz Hyper-plane theorem ( for symplectic hypersurface) given in the paper. But it is interesting to note that the notion " Stein" was never mentioned in the paper. Carlo,  thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yi Lin: what Donaldson proves is really that the complement is a Weinstein manifold; one then has to invoke Eliashberg's theorem (as in Cieliebak-Eliashberg's book) to deform the data to be Stein. This aspect of Donaldson's theory was highlighted in work of Paul Biran.